# Holomorphic homomorphism of complex reductive groups is algebraic

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Could you hint (or give a reference) for: A holomorphic group homomorphism between complex reductive algebraic groups is algebraic.

Thank you!

Comment: It suffices to treat the connected case, which is Proposition D.2.1 in the article *Reductive Group Schemes* in http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/PanoramasSyntheses/2014/42-43/html/smf_pano-synth_42-43.php (briefly: reduce to target ${\rm{GL}}_n$ and the source either a torus or semisimple, and for tori use the maximal compact subgroup and Lie algebra considerations whereas for semisimple source use a graph argument with semisimple Lie algebras).